# View not loading new data after http request in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to submit data from a form and display the result in the view directly after http request returns a result. But it's not happening.

```
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.add = function (){         
   $http.post('add.php',$scope.formData,{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
   .then(function (result) {
      console.log(result.data);          
      if (result){
         $scope.data = result.data;
      }                   
   });
};
```

And this is `add.php`. In this file I just want to return the posted data in `json`.

```
function index(){
   $data = $this->input->post();
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I find it returns `false` value. I wonder how I process data submitted with `post` method using `$http.post` like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to pass data to *add.php* service

```
$scope.add = function (){  
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'add.php',
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      },
    data:$scope.formData

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data.data;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);

      });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in **PHP**:

```
$data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
```

In **AngularJS**, inject **$httpParamSerializerJQLike** in your service/factory

```
$scope.add = function (){  
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/add.php',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.formData);

    }).then(function resolve(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.data = response.data.data;
    }, function reject(response) {
        console.log(response);

    });
 }
```